# Transfer cookies to another device on Chrome

Tags: facebook, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to move the login session of Facebook from one device to another device. Both the devices use chrome browser. I tried using a cookie extension to export the cookies and then import the cookie on another device. The cookies in the logged-in device are:

[image]

In the destination device, after importing the cookie, when I open Facebook.com it asks for credentials as usual. Also, it replaces a few cookies and removes some (like presence).

My question is, is there anything facebook uses to stop transferring cookie sessions? How FB detect that it's a different device?

It's for leaning purposes to figure out the attacks and defenses in the cookies system.

Comment: There’s probably a good amount of [device fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by just creating c_user and xs cookies manually and copying the values in the other browser. I think I was doing something wrong while exporting or importing the whole cookie set.

Comment: Hi, how did you do it. I'm also trying it but with no success